# ASP.Net: Eval Format for money expressions

Tags: asp.net

how I can format my database-query in a list view with 2 signs after comma?

Now: 100
Should be: 100,00

Now: 75,3
Should be: 75,30

How I get it when I insert the data in the list view with Eval(xxx)?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
<%# Eval("myField", "{0:c}") %>
```

will format the value using the locale-specific currency settings.

Answer (score 16):

this will give you the exact format you are looking for:

```
<%# Eval("currency", "{0:0,00}") %>
```

or this will give you the amount in the local currency (based on the webserver's locale).

```
<%# Eval("currency", "{0:c}") %>
```